# Reduce render file size in After Effects CC 2017

Tags: after-effects

I'm using Adobe After Effects CC 2017 and I want to reduce the render file size. However, I Googled all day and I cannot find any for CC 2017. All of them says that change the format to H.264 but we cannot do that in CC 2017. Please help me.

Comment: What codec and container are you exporting to now? How big are the files you are getting? How big do you want the files to be?

Answer (score 2):

To render H.264 it's actually very easy.

1. From your Project window, select the sequence you wish to render.
2. Right click->Export Media (or File->Export Media)
3. In the Video tab, select H.264 for format

Then, in the basic video settings below, you can change to smaller-than-original resolution, low bit rates, etc.

If you are trying to export a Quicktime file that uses H.264, that's much more challenging.  When you select Quicktime, Premiere Pro gives you a useless menu of Presets that were relevant for about six months during the early 1990s.  Ignore all of them, as they are stupid.  Instead, look down to where there's a Video Codec selector.  Click on that and you'll see tons of options, including H.264.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more detail? I'm using cc 2017

Answer (score 1):

I remember searching for this all day long some months ago.

Adobe seems to have discontinued some of the options that were available in previous versions of AE.

You'll have to get your hands on Adobe Media Encoder.

Once installed, it will appear as an option under `Composition` in AE, saying `Add to Adobe Media Encoder Queue`, just above the regular `Add to Render Queue` option.
(Prior to installation, this is greyed out.)

Click on that and all the good old export options will appear.